# Add some padding before icon

Tags: search, flutter-layout, textfield

I want to add some padding between the edge of my search bar and the search icon...Can someone please let me know how it can be added? Below is the code I have...Thank you very much.
[image]

```
Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        right: w * 0.02,
                        left: w * 0.05,
                      ),
                      child: CupertinoTextField(
                        onChanged: (v) {
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        autofocus: true,
                        controller: searchAppTextEditingController,
                        placeholder: 'Search for an app',
                        prefix: Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          size: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flutter, everything is a widget. Padding can be added with the `Padding` widget.

In your case, you can start by trying to add another `Padding` widget for the `Icon` (the `prefix` of your `CupertinoTextField`).

Comment: Thank you user1032613